# ASP.Net menu acting strange in IE

Tags: html, css

I made a site using ASP.net and it works fine in Firefox and Chrome but in IE my menu becomes huge and extends past my page border. The site is www.radoart.co.za . Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is cause by the your .menu class

if you set the padding-left and padding-right values to 5px it will work fine in IE too because its working fine at my end if i set the padding-left and padding-right vlaues to 5px.